# The solution to algebraic equation formulated with Siegel modular function and hyperelliptic integrals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, power-series, several-complex-variables

[Here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-0-8176-4578-6_18)  is an article to solve the algebraic equation with degree above 4

For example, $t^5=a$, we get one solution to the equation:
$$t=e^{\frac{1}{n}\int^a_1 \frac{1}{x}}$$, generalizing this result by replacing  the exponential with Siegel modular function and  the integral with hyperelliptic integrals, we can get every solution to an algebraic equation with degree above 5  formulated by Siegel modular function and  hyperelliptic integrals, please see  [David Mumford Tate lecture on Theta $\textrm{II}$ Jacobian page 266](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-0-8176-4578-6_18)  for more detail .

Could anyone write down the formula of the solution formulated by Siegel modular function and  hyperelliptic integrals(or by other modular function and  hyperelliptic integrals)? I think it may be like $$x= \lambda^{\int \frac{x^i}{\sqrt{F(x)}}dx}$$ where $\lambda$ is the Siegel modular function( I do not know it's form, please write it down)

Now Could we extend this result to algebraic equation like $$p_0(x) + p_1(x) \cdot y + p_2(x)\cdot y^2 + \cdots + p_n(x)\cdot y^n $$ with coefficients of $p_i(x) \in Q[x]$ to have solutions of $y$ which is the counterpart of $x$ in $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_nx^n=0$ in the article($a_i$ is the counterpart of $p_i(x)$)?

Comment: Still no answer or comment

Comment: a reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical

Comment: more http://tieba.baidu.com/p/1903646954?pn=1&traceid=

Comment: Jacobi Theta function : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SiegelThetaFunction.html